# Why isn't git submodule init and git submodule update one command?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Whenever I use submodules in `git` find myself doing

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

What's the logic in two commands when you basicly do those commands every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git submodule init` initializes the machinery, whereas `git submodule update` pulls in new changes for the submodules. If you're adding a submodule, there's nothing to update yet, so you only need to run `git submodule init` to initialize the repo. (It creates a `.gitmodules` file, as well as some stuff in `.git/` for tracking submodules.)

Comment: And I *think* that you should only have to do `init` once, but you might do `update` repeatedly. At least in theory. Though I use a wrapper that does `git submodule status`, `... init`, `... update`, `... status`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the separation, but an easy workaround would be to use an alias.

```
alias gitrox="git submodule init && git submodule update"
```

Answer (score 0):

They do have a way to do it in one call:

```
submodule update --init
```

source :
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-init--ltpathgt82308203